# How to get current index of UIBarButtonItem to remove it by clicking event?

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm in the process of learning Objective-C and iOS development. So, I implemented removing of `UIBarButtonItem` from `UIToolBar` on `UIControlEventTouchDown` event in the `selector`. But this works **really** bad and the code is not very declarative as you see:

```
- (void)barButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
     NSArray * const itemsArray = userToolbar.items;
     NSMutableArray * mutableItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemsArray];
    [mutableItems removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [userToolbar setItems: mutableItems animated:YES];
}
```

So as you see I removed item accordingly to its index in the `userToolbar` items array. It's not what I really want. I have on my `UIToolBar` nearly 10-12 `UIBarItemButtons` and I want define one common event for them all: removing it from the bar by clicking on it. So I need something like this:

`[mutableItems removeObjectAtIndex:sender.currentIndexInToolBarItemsArray]`

So, the question how can I implement this?

Comment: So why is this approach not good? Can't you just replace `0` with `[arr indexOfObject:sender]` and live happily forever?

Comment: even better: `[copyArr removeObject:sender];` - I made this an answer, please accept & upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the object at the constant index 0, use the `removeObject:` method of `NSMutableArray`:

```
[mutableItems removeObject:sender];
```

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov yes, pretty much, however it removes all occurrences of an object (see the docs).